# Inner join database query?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables, `items_table` and `item_bidding_table`.

`items_table` has the following columns:

```
id, name, desc, quantity, unit_price
```

while `item_bidding_table` has these columns

```
id, item_id(FK), amount
```

where `item_id` is a foreign key to  `item_bidding_table`.

I need a query to return full row from `items_table` (all columns) for these conditions:

1. `amount` value in `item_bidding_table` must be greater than `unit_price` in `items_table`
2. returned `unit_price` value must be the maximum amount in `item_bidding_table`

**Example:**

`items_table`:

```
[id | name | desc | quantity | unit_price ]
[1  | rice | food |    5     |     10     ]
[2  | Eggs | food |    6     |     15     ]
```

`item_bidding_table`:

```
[id | item_id | amount ]
[1  |    1    |    9   ]
[2  |    1    |    12  ]
```

Expected output:

```
 [1  | rice | food |    5     |     12     ]
```

where **12** is the largest amount in the `item_bidding_table`.

So what's the query required to return this output?

Comment: what defines the latest amount in the item_bidding_table. There is no timestamp column there to sort on. Or did you mean the maximum value out of all the values which are greater then unit price in items_table?

Comment: maximum value that greater than unit_price for specific item

Comment: We like to see your best effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below query to get the desired result.

```
select 
    i.id, i.name, i.desc, i.quantity,
    max(ib.amount) 
from 
    items_table i 
inner join 
    item_bidding_table ib on i.id = ib.item_id 
where 
    ib.amount > i.unit_price 
group by 
    i.id, i.name, i.desc, i.quantity
```

Hint: whenever you need to use aggregate functions like (min, max, avg) etc think of group by clause and try to frame your query in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM item_bidding_table 
    ORDER BY amount DESC
) t
JOIN items_table t ON t.id = b.item_id
WHERE t.unit_price <= b.amount
GROUP BY t.id
```

The subquery orders the bids in descending order. With the addition of the `group by` you then get the maximum bid with each order. Finally the `join` and the `where` clause are needed to satisfy your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

select a.*, b.amt as amount from items_table  a

cross apply (select max(amount) as amt from item_bidding_table where item_id = a.id group by item_id) b

Answer (score -1):

This would work in almost all SQL backends and be efficient (also doesn't depend on items_table id being unique - you didn't really say if it were or not):

```
   select name , desc , quantity, amount
    from items_table i
    inner join 
    (select item_id, max(amount) as amount 
    from item_bidding_table
   where amount > unit_price
   group by item_id) tmp on i.id = tmp.item_id
```

Note: It wouldn't matter with Max() in this query but whenever there are joins, first do the aggregate then join.